How to add total density to geom_density when split into different factors
I am trying to plot a density plot of proportion of time a beetle spent in 4 different areas.
I have another categorical factor of time of day which is 2 levels.
I have managed to split the data into the habitats using facet_wrap, and split the proportions into the factors, but as I would like to compare the effects of time of day on proportion, I would like to display the pooled proportion data ontop of time of day.
Here is my current code and graph:
Timeserod <- 
  plotsplit$erodius %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  ungroup()

etimesplits <- ggplot(data = Timeserod, aes(x = Proportion, col = Time)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~Habitat)
etimesplits

Density plot, want to add total proportios
I thought about trying the rbind function as used in the answer to this question, however I don't think I'll b able to work this with my other factor of habitat.
Does anyone know a way to do this?
Here is some sample data:
Number  Family  Time    Habitat Proportion
1   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.32
2   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.07
3   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.27
4   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.24
5   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0
6   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.05
7   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.46
8   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.06
9   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.23
10  erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.44
1   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.17
2   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.08
3   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
4   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
5   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.14
6   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.04
7   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.68
8   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.11
9   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
10  erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.48
1   erodius Midday  Sand    0.23
2   erodius Midday  Sand    0
3   erodius Midday  Sand    0
4   erodius Midday  Sand    0.4
5   erodius Midday  Sand    0.01
6   erodius Midday  Sand    0.08
7   erodius Midday  Sand    0.15
8   erodius Midday  Sand    0.29
9   erodius Midday  Sand    0.15
10  erodius Midday  Sand    0.34
1   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.03
2   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.4
3   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.8
4   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.53
5   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.54
6   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.97
7   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0
8   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.57
9   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.56
10  erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.18
1   erodius Midday  Pine    0.24
2   erodius Midday  Pine    0.35
3   erodius Midday  Pine    0.97
4   erodius Midday  Pine    0.26
5   erodius Midday  Pine    0
6   erodius Midday  Pine    0.2
7   erodius Midday  Pine    0.08
8   erodius Midday  Pine    0.54
9   erodius Midday  Pine    0.27
10  erodius Midday  Pine    0.36
2   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
3   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
4   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.03
5   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
6   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
7   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.42
8   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.08
9   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.01
10  erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.28
1   erodius Midday  Soil    0
2   erodius Midday  Soil    0.65
3   erodius Midday  Soil    0
4   erodius Midday  Soil    0.23
5   erodius Midday  Soil    0
6   erodius Midday  Soil    0
7   erodius Midday  Soil    0
8   erodius Midday  Soil    0
9   erodius Midday  Soil    0.58
10  erodius Midday  Soil    0.02
1   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
2   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.03
3   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.05
4   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.44
5   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
6   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
7   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
8   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
9   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.04
10  erodius Afternoon   Soil    0


You can add another geom_density() layer to your existing plot with a new aesthetic that does not split on time-of-day:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

df <- read.table(sep="", header=TRUE, text=c("
Number  Family  Time    Habitat Proportion
1   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.32
2   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.07
3   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.27
4   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.24
5   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0
6   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.05
7   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.46
8   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.06
9   erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.23
10  erodius Midday  Cardboard   0.44
1   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.17
2   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.08
3   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
4   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
5   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.14
6   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.04
7   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.68
8   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.11
9   erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0
10  erodius Afternoon   Cardboard   0.48
1   erodius Midday  Sand    0.23
2   erodius Midday  Sand    0
3   erodius Midday  Sand    0
4   erodius Midday  Sand    0.4
5   erodius Midday  Sand    0.01
6   erodius Midday  Sand    0.08
7   erodius Midday  Sand    0.15
8   erodius Midday  Sand    0.29
9   erodius Midday  Sand    0.15
10  erodius Midday  Sand    0.34
1   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.03
2   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.4
3   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.8
4   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.53
5   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.54
6   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.97
7   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0
8   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.57
9   erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.56
10  erodius Afternoon   Sand    0.18
1   erodius Midday  Pine    0.24
2   erodius Midday  Pine    0.35
3   erodius Midday  Pine    0.97
4   erodius Midday  Pine    0.26
5   erodius Midday  Pine    0
6   erodius Midday  Pine    0.2
7   erodius Midday  Pine    0.08
8   erodius Midday  Pine    0.54
9   erodius Midday  Pine    0.27
10  erodius Midday  Pine    0.36
2   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
3   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
4   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.03
5   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
6   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0
7   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.42
8   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.08
9   erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.01
10  erodius Afternoon   Pine    0.28
1   erodius Midday  Soil    0
2   erodius Midday  Soil    0.65
3   erodius Midday  Soil    0
4   erodius Midday  Soil    0.23
5   erodius Midday  Soil    0
6   erodius Midday  Soil    0
7   erodius Midday  Soil    0
8   erodius Midday  Soil    0
9   erodius Midday  Soil    0.58
10  erodius Midday  Soil    0.02
1   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
2   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.03
3   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.05
4   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.44
5   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
6   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
7   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
8   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
9   erodius Afternoon   Soil    0.04
10  erodius Afternoon   Soil    0
"))

head(df)
#>   Number  Family   Time   Habitat Proportion
#> 1      1 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.32
#> 2      2 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.07
#> 3      3 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.27
#> 4      4 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.24
#> 5      5 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.00
#> 6      6 erodius Midday Cardboard       0.05

etimesplits <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Proportion, col = Time)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~Habitat) +
  geom_density(data=df, aes(x=Proportion), 
               colour="black", linetype=2, inherit.aes=FALSE)

etimesplits


Created on 2024-05-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! this works like a charm, just need to add lines to represent the means but i reckon i can work that out
